# Actionscript delegate function trouble... (myFunction).toString() prints function Function() {}

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, delegates, anonymous-function

I've got a Vector of `ViewToActionMap` objects, which have following constructor:

```
public function ViewToActionMap(_forModule:eModule, 
                                _forAction:eViewAction,
                                _toFunction:Function,
                                _withArgs:Array=null):void{         
            forModule   = _forModule;
            forAction   = _forAction;
            toFunction  = _toFunction;
            withArgs    = _withArgs;
        }
```

(`eModule` / `eViewAction` / `withArgs` aren't relevant to my post)

So my vector looks like this (for brevity, i've only included its first object..):

```
const actionMappings:Vector.<ViewToActionMap> = new <ViewToActionMap>
               [new ViewToActionMap(eModule.WELCOME,    
                eViewAction.GP_CONTINUE_BUTTON,     
                startGame,  //<--- the source of my troubles!
                null)
               ]
```

Where `startGame` is a simple function:

```
function startGame():void{  }
```

///////////////   so here's the problem  //////////////

if I loop through the properties of actionMappings[0], here is the output:

```
gpContinueButton
welcome
function Function() {}    //<---------- why isn't this working?
null
```

Why is the value of `.toFunction` an empty function, instead of a reference to startGame()????

Thanks!

Comment: Does startGame contain any logical lines? I apologize if you omitted them for example purposes only.

Comment: nope, not yet:   `function startGame():void  { trace("call me!") }; `  ;)

Comment: haha, i didn't paste that right (";" at the end)... i think that would cause a compiler error.   :P

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

it seems that tracing the value of `".toFunction"` simply yields this: `function Function() {}`

Once i fixed an unrelated bug, I was able to call startGame() successfully.